# Vue fullcalendar dynamic events not showing

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have used the fullcalendar plugin on my nuxt 3 projects and I need to set events on the calendar but my events are coming from API so I have taken on `const upcomingEventData = ref([])` const and after API response I am updating the variable with events return by API but it is not reflecting on the calendar.

```html
<FullCalendar :options="calendarOptions">
   <template v-slot:eventContent="arg">
      <el-tag :type="arg.event.extendedProps.type" size="large">
       {{arg.event.title}}
      </el-tag>
   </template>
</FullCalendar>
```

```js
const upcomingEventData = ref([]);

const calendarOptions = {
  ...FullCalendar.options,
  initialView: "dayGridMonth",
  dateClick: handleDateClick(),
  dayHeaderContent: function (arg) {
    return arg.text.toUpperCase();
  },
  },
  events: upcomingEventData.value,
  eventColor: "#FFFFFF",
  eventChange: function (arg) {
    console.log('Data--> ' , arg);
  },
  headerToolbar: {
    start: "today prev,next", 
    center: "title",
    end: "dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay",
  },
  buttonText: {
    today: "Today",
    month: "Month",
    week: "Week",
    day: "Day",
    list: "List",
  },
  buttonIcons: {
    prev: "chevron-left",
    next: "chevron-right",
    prevYear: "chevrons-left", // double chevron
    nextYear: "chevrons-right", // double chevron
  },
};

const getEventData = async () => {
  const { data, error } = await useGetQuery("event/get");
  if (error.value) {
    useErrorHandling(error.value);
  }
  if (data.value) {
    let response = data.value.data;
    upcomingEventData.value = [];
    response.data.forEach((element, index) => {
      upcomingEventData.value[index] = {
        title: element.eventTitle,
        date: formatDate(new Date(element.eventDate), "YYYY-MM-DD"),
        type: "success",
      }
    });
  }
};

onMounted(() => {
  getEventData();
});
```

I think I need to refresh the calendar again once `upcomingEventData` constant is update. Kindly please help me and ask if any more details is required.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you wrote `events: upcomingEventData.value` this passes the values into the calendar once, and once only. It doesn't maintain a sync between fullCalendar and the original variable. If you want a dynamic event feed, a better approach would be to use one of the methods supported by fullCalendar - see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-function

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your comment. I have fixed this issue using vue computed property. I have just wrapped the `calendarOptions` constant with the computed `const calendarOptions = computed(() => { ... }`. Hope this will be right way if not please correct me

Comment: If it works for you, then that's fine - "right" is always a bit subjective. But please...add that as an Answer so it's available and searchable for others who might have the same problem. Comments cannot be searched, and you also don't get reputation points for them :-)

Comment: The only thing I would point out is that if you use one of the fullcalendar methods I linked to above, it gives you the ability to automatically filter the events by date, so you only download the events which the calendar is actually displaying. This can be very efficient if your database has a large list of older or future events, because you probably don't want to download a huge list every time, when most users are unlikely to look at them. fullcalendar then automatically requests extra event data from the server if/when the user changes the date on the calendar.

Comment: @ADyson Sure thing I have added things as answers. Thank you very much for your time! Also please vote up answer so everyone can get attention

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed this issue using vue computed property. I have just wrapped the calendarOptions constant with the computed const `calendarOptions = computed(() => { ... }`.

```js
const calendarOptions = computed(() => {
  return {
    ...FullCalendar.options,
    initialView: "dayGridMonth",
    dateClick: handleDateClick(),
    },
    events: upcomingEventData.value,
    eventColor: "#FFFFFF",
    eventChange: function (arg) {},
    headerToolbar: {
      start: "today prev,next",
      center: "title",
      end: "dayGridMonth,dayGridWeek,dayGridDay",
    },
    buttonText: {
      today: "Today",
      month: "Month",
      week: "Week",
      day: "Day",
      list: "List",
    },
    buttonIcons: {
      prev: "chevron-left",
      next: "chevron-right",
      prevYear: "chevrons-left", // double chevron
      nextYear: "chevrons-right", // double chevron
    },
  };
});
```